# gulp - Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'

Tags: php, laravel, gulp

when i type in terminal in laravel dei project gulp always say

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\codehacking\gulpfile.js:1:76)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

and try `npm install` and `npm install --global gulp` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing laravel-elixir manually in your project directory.

```
npm install laravel-elixir --save-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

If you encountered this problem "Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'" I have a solution for you. Follow the commands below:

- npm install node-sass@latest
- npm uninstall laravel-elixir
- npm uninstall session
- npm install --save laravel-elixir
- npm install --save session
- gulp

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, I tried above solution and many other, did not work for me. Following two commands fixed my error.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

npm install node-gyp
```

The complete solution is on the following link:
[https://catalin.me/how-to-fix-node-js-gyp-err-cant-find-python-executable-python-on-windows/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq32V.jpg)

My OS is windows.

Then in my Laravel 5.2 on the root of project I ran following command

```
npm install
```

Then I ran gulp command

```
gulp
```

gulp started working:
Gulp Command Image
[image: Gulp Command Image]